# XAML make the image and text scrollable

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using listview to display images and text. Now i need to make it scrollable. I need to display the listview horizontal with scrollable.
Thanks for the help

```
 <Grid x:Name="Playlist" Visibility="{Binding IsShow}" Height="540" Width="960">
        <ListView Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollection}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" Margin="0,279,0,0">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" MaxHeight="150">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="144" Width="256"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                     </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ListView set the attached [ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) property to [Auto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.scrollbarvisibility.aspx) (show scrollbar if needed) or Visible (scrollbar is always visible).

Example:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to adjust the size/color of the Scroll bar